# How to change model names in Abaqus wrt an array list?

Tags: python, abaqus

I am trying to change Model names in Abaqus with respect to the values in an array list. At first, I created two array lists and divided them but it is not a good idea as I will have 100 values later on in Beam_h and Beam_w and the values will repeat.. What can I do if I want to have my model names be: `model20-10`, `model30-10`, `model50-10`? Also, the loop I used so far gives me `model0`, `model1`, `model2`. What to write in the loop to get desired model names?

```py
#Here is the code,

Beam_h = [20, 30, 50] #Beam Height mm
Beam_w = [10, 10, 10] #Beam width mm 
divide_list = [x/y for x, y in zip(Beam_h, Beam_w)]  ##I do not want to divide.It's wrong

for values in divide_list:                                               ##looping not right
    mdb.Model(name='model'+str(values))
    BeamModel = mdb.Model(name='model'+str(values))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you just need to figure out `string concatenation`.

You need to check for duplicate model names as well. Because Abaqus replaces the already existing model if you create a model with duplicate name. 
To address this issue, you can use `dictionary` object in following way:

```
dup_Models = dict()  # To store the model names and repeating count
for x,y in zip(Beam_h,Beam_w):
    modelName = 'model%d-%d'%(x,y) # String concatenation - You can use other ways also!
    if modelName not in dup_Models:
        dup_Models[modelName] = 1
        umodelName = modelName      # Unique model name (No Duplication)
    else:
        dup_Models[modelName] += 1
        umodelName = '%s_%d'%(modelName,dup_Models[modelName])

    BeamModel = mdb.Model(name=umodelName)
```

One last thing, you cannot use `.`(dot) in model name(Abaqus throws an error). So,  if `Beam_h` and `Beam_w` has values other than integers, then you have to name the model some other way, for ex. `w=10.5 and w=20.5 --> model10pt5-20pt5`.

Comment: Hi, I had to change the second line with len() command for my model. But it gives me 6 models instead of 3 as it is multiplying. What to write to find the output as previous.                                                                                                              ``for i in range(len(Beam_h)):
    for j in range (len(Beam_w)):
        modelName = 'model%d-%d'%(Beam_h[i],Beam_w[j])``

Comment: The code you provided in this comment, with that it should give 9 models not 6. Anyways, you have to use ONLY one `for loop` instead of two. ```for i in range(len(Beam_h)):
    modelName = 'model%d-%d'%(Beam_h[i],Beam_w[i])```